# Typescript; mapboxgl is not defined in combination with mapbox gl directions

Tags: typescript, aurelia, mapbox-gl, typescript-typings

I am using Aurelia/Typescript + Mapbox in a project of mine. But I am having troubles using `mapbox-gl` and `mapbox-gl-directions` in combination with typscript.

For `mapbox-gl` I am using [this](https://github.com/dobrud/typed-mapbox-gl/) typscript definition file. I can initialize a map and and markers/layers to it etc.

Firstly, what I am trying to do is add markers (starting point and destination, which works) and add a line between them with a logical route. For the line between the markers I am trying to use `mapbox-gl-directions`. Sadly `mapbox-gl-directions` is not included in this definition file, so I am trying to create one for myself.

I have created the following typescript definition file. It obvious that  a lot is still missing, but this should get me started.

```
declare namespace mapboxgl {
    export class Directions extends Control {
        constructor(options?: DirectionOptions);
    }

    export interface DirectionOptions {
        unit?: string; 
        profile?: string;
        container?: string;
        proximity?: Array<number>;
    }
}

declare module 'mapbox-gl-directions' {
    export = mapboxgl;
}
```

I created a custom component `Map` for the `mapbox-gl` map. These are my imports on the `.ts.` file. They work fine and I get both `.js` files in my `dist` folder when I run the project.

```
import * as mapboxgl from 'mapbox-gl';
import * as mapboxgldirections from 'mapbox-gl-directions';
```

The problems start when I try to use the directions in my `initializeMap` function.

```
initializeMap = () : void => {
       this.map = new mapboxgl.Map({
            container: this.options.mapElement,
            style: this.options.style,
            center: [this.options.startLongitude, this.options.startLatitude],
            zoom: this.options.startingZoom
       });  
       // It gives an error on the following line
       this.map.addControl(new mapboxgldirections.Directions());
   }
```

I get the following error:

```
 mapbox-gl-directions.js:4 Uncaught ReferenceError: mapboxgl is not defined
```

It looks like `mapbox-gl-directions` has a dependency on `mapbox-gl` and should be used after `mapbox-gl` is included, which is only logical. But it is generating the map with no problems, so why is `mapbox` not defined, even though I use `mapbox.Map` without any problems?

It is a lot of information but here is the question. How can I make sure `mapbox-gl` is ready when I try to use `mapbox-gl-directions`?

Note that I installed both modules with NPM

```
 npm install mapbox-gl --save
 npm install mapbpx-gl-directions --save
```